# How to sum even and odd values with one for-loop and no if-condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am taking a programming class in college and one of the exercises in the problem sheet was to write this code:

```
number = int(input())
x = 0
y = 0
for n in range(number):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        x += n
    else:
        y += n
print(x)
print(y)
```

using only one "for" loop, and no "while" or "if".

> The purpose of the code is to find the sum of the even and the sum of
> the odd numbers from zero to the number inputted and print it to the
> screen.

Be reminded that at this time we aren't supposed to know about
functions.

I've been trying for a long time now and can't seem to find a way of doing it without using "if" statements to know if the loop variable is even or odd.

Comment: Can you please share with us what you've been trying so far - and exactly where you are stuck?  Thanks.

Comment: You phrased this question a bit oddly - you stressed "using only one for loop" but then just mentioned no if statements just in brackets. But your snippet already *does* have only one for loop, so avoiding the if statement is not just a footnote but sorta the whole point. I had to read your question a couple of times to notice the full requirements.

Comment: @ArthurTacca you are absolutely correct after i posted it i noticed that as you said the whole point of it was to eliminate the if statements, i only wrote it like that because it was how the exercise was phrased in problem sheet

Comment: "How 7 Years Old Gauss Summed Natural Numbers from 1 to 100?" https://physicsdb.com/sum-natural-numbers/ The best answers will build on this and adapt the formula.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for n in range(number):
    x += (1 - n % 2) * n
    y += (n % 2) * n
```

Answer (score 17):

Purely for educational purposes (and a bit of fun), here is a solution that does not use any `for` loops at all. (Granted, in the underlying logic of the functions, there are at least five loops.)

```
num = list(range(int(input('Enter number: '))))

even = num[::2]
odd = num[1::2]

print('Even list:', even)
print('Odd list:', odd)

print('Even:', sum(even))
print('Odd:', sum(odd))
```

Output:

```
Enter number: 10
Even list: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
Odd list: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
Even: 20
Odd: 25
```

How does it work?

- The `input()` function returns a `str` object, which is converted into an integer using the `int()` function.
- The integer is wrapped in the `range()` and `list()` functions to convert the given number into a list of values within that range.

  - This is a convention you will use/see a lot through your Python career.
- List slicing is used to get every second element in the list. Given the list is based at zero, these will be even numbers.
- Slice the same list again, starting with the second element, and get every second element ... odd numbers.

  - Link to a [nice SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/6340496) regarding slicing in Python.
- The simply use the `sum()` function to get the sums.

Comment: That is fun and clever, but I see *five* loops in it: `list`, the two slices, and the two `sum` calls. (I'm not counting the loops to render the strings in the first two `print` calls.)

Comment: the op's requirement was only one "for" loop so this meets the requirement

Comment: @MichaelGeary - Fair point!  I'll revise the commentary.  Thanks.

Comment: If we create the list on a seperate line we could do `sum_even, sum_odd = [sum(num[i::2]) for i in [None, 1]]`. Maybe the input and the creation of the list could be part of this line too if we use the new walrus operator (`:=`) but I still haven't installed the new Python version so I can't check.

Answer (score 11):

You asked for a solution with *one* loop, but how about a solution with *no* loop?

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Formula) that the sum of the numbers from `1` to `n` is `(n+1)*n/2`. Thus, the sum of *even* numbers is `2 * (m+1)*m/2` with `m = n//2` (i.e. `floor(n/2)`). The sum of odd can then be calculated by the sum of all numbers minus the sum of even numbers.

```
n = 12345
m = n // 2
e = (m+1)*m
o = (n+1)*n//2 - e
```

Verification:

```
>>> e, e==sum(i for i in range(n+1) if i % 2 == 0)
38112102 True
>>> o, o==sum(i for i in range(n+1) if i % 2 == 1)
38105929 True
```

Note: This calculates the sums for number up to and *including* `n`.

Answer (score 6):

There is also mathematical way:

```
num = int(input("Enter number:"))
odd = ((num+1)/2)**2
even = num*(num+1)/2 - odd
```

The sum of the first n odd numbers is n^2. To get count of odd numbers we use `(num+1)/2`. To get sum of even numbers, we could use similar approach, but I preferred, subtracting `odd` from the sum of the first n numbers, which is n*(n+1)/2.

Comment: This is absolutely the right way to do it. Gauss discovered this formula; no need to loop, use memory, or increase the complexity.

Answer (score 4):

```
for n in range(1,number,2):
  x += n
  y += n-1
print(y)
print(x)
```

This code has the same output with the example.

Comment: This will fail if the upper bound is even.

Comment: If `number` is `3` the output for `y` is `0`.

Comment: Although this doesn't quite work, I do think it comes closest to capturing the spirit of the original question. It doesn't just use the mathematical formula (obviously in the real world that's the best solution but isn't the point here) and doesn't use any tricks to simulate an if statement. It's a pity the question doesn't allow a single if statement outside the loop to tidy up the difference between even and odd maximum number.

Comment: This is exactly what i've done, but then again it failled when i tried doing it for even numbers, and if i corrected it to do the even numbers right than it would fail in the odd numbers, but as @ArthurTacca this was sort of the idea i had when I wrote the question.

Answer (score 4):

Ternary operator:

```
for n in range(number):
  x += (n,0)[n%2]
  y += (0,n)[n%2]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are a beginner. I wouldn't like to confuse you with slicing operators complex implementation.

**As you mentioned**

> The purpose of the code is to find the sum of the even and the sum of
> the odd numbers from zero to the number inputted and print it to the
> screen.

There is no need to find the initial number is **odd/even**
And your program is **wrong** if you want to include the input number in calculating the even/odd **sum**.

**Example**

**Input**

> 5

**Expected Output**

> 6
> 9

**Explanation**

Even Sum : 2+4 = 6

Odd Sum : 1+3+5 = 9

**Your Output**

> 6 4  (wrong output)

The **range()** function will exclude the number. It will only iterate from 0 to 4 while the input is 5. so if you want to include 5, you should add 1 to the **number** while passing it in the **range()** function.

```
number = int(input())
x = 0
y = 0
for n in range(number+1):
    x += (1 - n % 2) * n  #this will add 0 if not even
    y += (n % 2) * n      #this will add 0 if not odd
print(x)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my 2cents if we are allowed to use numpy.

```
import numpy as np
number = int(input())

l = np.array(range(number)) 
print('odd:',sum(l % 2 * l))
print('even:', sum((1- l % 2) * l))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to use a list

```
number = int( input() )
counts = [ 0, 0 ]
for n in range( number ):
    counts[ n % 2 ] += n
print( counts[ 0 ] )
print( counts[ 1 ] )
```

Answer (score 2):

There's another way which sums the odd and even indices together in the for loop based on the remainder modulo 2:

```
number = int(input())
odd = 0
even = 0
for i in range(len(number)):
    odd += i * (i % 2)
    even += i * ((i + 1) % 2)

print (odd, even)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
number = 1000000
x = 0
y = 0
[(x:=x+n, y:=y+(n+1)) for n in range(0,number,2)]
print(f'{x}, {y}')
```

This uses a list comprehension and the new Python assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

Sum of first n numbers is **n*(n+1)/2* (Mathematically derived). So if we know the value of *n* then we can find the sum of all numbers from 1 to n.

If we find the sum of all odd numbers before *n* and subratract it from the sum of first *n* we get he sum of all even numbers before *n*.

Here's the code:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
odd = 0
for i in range(1,n+1,2):
    odd += i
even = int(n*(n+1)/2) - odd
print("even:",even,"odd:",odd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of my personal favorites:

```
number = 20
even, odd = 0, 0
for i in range(number):
    # use bitwise operators to decide if lsb is 1 (odd) or 0 even
    even += (i&1 == 0) * i
    odd += (i&1 == 1) * i
print("even:", even, "odd:", odd)

Output: 
even: 90 odd: 100
```

Comment: The current code will raise a syntax-error. I assume you meant `i & 1`. (And since your solution depends on bitwise operators, you might as well simplify to: `even += (~i & 1) * i` and `odd += (i & 1) * i`).

Comment: Not sure what happened there with my copy and paste  but I will take it as a lesson to proofread the code section of the answer before I post it.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @ekhumoro I prefer my revised answer for readability purposes.

Comment: And that's also why I prefer my version ;-) Anyway, +1 for improving your answer.